# No option to start Ubuntu OS after installtion

Tags: boot, windows, bios

I successfully installed Ubuntu however, every time I startup my lapyop it goes straight to windows 8 OS. I cant find the option to switch OS in the bios screen. Please help!!!

Comment: Fix your boot loader using Boot Repair (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the bios interface by typing fxx (usually f12 but depends on the manufacturer) right after powering your cpu. I have to do it when the Asus logo shows up.

Once in this interface you can either change the boot order (put windowsboot-manager in the second place) or override the boot manually. Usually your ubuntu booter (grub) has the name of the drive you installed ubuntu on. But once again if you don't know which boot-option is the right, just try them all.

I can just advise to look in the bios settings, once your in just look around. 
If you need further help post a few screens.